# WPF Create sibling window and close current one

Tags: c#, wpf

What I need is such an event handler in my window class.

```
void someEventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyNewWindow mnw = new MyNewWindow();
    mnw.Owner = Window.GetWindow(this);
    mnw.ShowDialog();
    this.Close();
}
```

Window.GetWindow(this) returns the parent window of the current window.

I had thought when the owner of the new window is the parent window of the current one, it would wait for the parent; and not the current one. But it did not work that way. Current window waits for the execution of the new and closes only after.

If I use Show() instead of ShowDialog() for some reason the window is not shown at all.

Probably I need some delegate methods but I am not sure where to start.

Edit: I guess I need to improve the question for future references:
The new window should be a dialog to the parent window. If I use Show() the parent window becomes accesible and I dont want that. If I use ShowDialog() it becomes a dialog to the current window, meaning that the current window does not close until the new window is closed, and I dont want that either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Closing a window causes any windows that it owns [to be closed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.close.aspx).

If you just want the owner window to not be visible, try this;

```
void someEventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyNewWindow mnw = new MyNewWindow();
    mnw.Owner = this;
    this.Hide(); // not required if using the child events below
    mnw.ShowDialog();
}
```

You'll likely want to hook up some event in the parent window that acts accordingly when you close the child window depending on your requirements.

**EDIT**

You could perhaps control the hiding of the (multiple parents) from the child;

```
void OnLoad(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  this.Owner.Hide();
}
void Closed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  this.Owner.Show();
}
```

Comment: Handling this in parent window would the easiest solution. but the child window can be called from various other windows which makes things complicated. I would need to modify the event handler in each of the parent windows, and I dont want that.

Comment: btw. calling this.Hide() before ShowDialog() ensured me a solution. The window is not closed but at least the user thinks so :) ty

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're trying to do you want to close the current window and replace it with a MyNewWindow that is a child of the window that was the original window's parent (probably the app's main window).

To do that you should be using:

```
    mnw.Owner = this.Owner;
```

instead of calling GetWindow, which gives you back the current Window instance. The purpose of GetWindow is to obtain the Window which contains some other UIElement, like a Button farther down the tree. When passing in a Window instance, you just get back what you passed in.

Comment: You got me right. But I want the new window appear as a dialog to the main window. Neither Show() nor ShowDialog() didnt provide this manner.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `ShowDialog()` blocks. That means, the method returns only when `mnw` is closed and only then is the original window closed.

If you change that to `Show()`, `mnw` is closed as soon as you call `Close()` on the original window. because `Window.GetWindow(this)` returns `this`. Thus, you set the owner to `this` and when you close `this`, `mnw` gets closed too. That leaves us with:

```
MyNewWindow mnw = new MyNewWindow();
mnw.Owner = this.Owner; // may not be necessary
mnw.Show();
this.Close();
```

This code seems to work for me.

Comment: When I call Show() the parent window becomes accessible. I want the new window to be a dialog of parent window.