# Switching from one window to another in WPF and making it active

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012

I'm pretty new to WPF and I'm trying to make a database system. What I currently have is a `Login` Window. When you enter the user and password you are supposed to go to another window `StudentInfoSystem` . The code I used is pretty basic and common.

```
var info = new StudentInfoSystem.MainWindow();
info.Show();        
this.Close();
```

So, what this would do, is after you press the login button, you get transferred to `StudentInfoSystem` and the login window closes. The problem I have with `Show()` is that it opens a window and immediately returns, right? It doesn't wait for the new window to close. So, my question is how can I open a new window and WORK with it? When I say work, I meant to show out information in my textboxes (In the NEWLY opened window) depending on the role the user has, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `window.Activate()` to focus the new window and/or `[any element].Focus()` to focus any element within window.

Comment: I figured out another temp solution. I just call the methods from the other window. (Ex: info.getStudentData())  Lol. It works fine for the moment, but If I want to expand my program and make it big, it's gonna get a lot messy than I would've ever anticipated. I'll try your answer tomorrow and give you feedback, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing the above code is in the button click handler for the Login Window, which would make the Login Window the parent of the StudentInfoSystem window.
Since WPF will close the parent and any child(ren) window(s) when closing the parent window, your StudentInfo window will also close when calling

```
this.Close();
```

One option might be to instead call

```
this.Hide();
```

but without seeing how the rest of your app is set up, not 100% sure this is the best approach.

Perhaps see these SO questions:

1. [wpf-create-sibling-window-and-close-current-one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672187/wpf-create-sibling-window-and-close-current-one)
2. [how-to-close-current-window-in-code-when-launching-new-window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19248822/how-to-close-current-window-in-code-when-launching-new-window)

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, this should do what you want:

```
info.ShowDialog();
```

You could also check `ShutdownMode` property. I would rather say, login window is sth you want to close after login, but do what you want :). Usage of `ShutdownMode` property:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);    
        this.ShutdownMode = System.Windows.ShutdownMode.OnLastWindowClose;
    }
}
```